# How to backup and restore in MySQL 5.2?

Tags: mysql

This is the command I used:

```
mysql> mysql -u root -p -h HOST sample < mysqldump.sql;
```

But I encountered an error as follows:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql -u root -p -h HOST sample < mysqldump.sql' at line 1
```

Hope you can help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open mysql terminal or konsole and then go to the directory where `mysqldump.sql` file is present. try:

```
shell> cd /file_path/;
shell> ls -al mysqldump.sql;
```

It should display your file. Also you dont need to specify HOST if you are logged on to the same server.

```
shell> mysql -u root -p sample < mysqldump.sql;
```

Answer (score 2):

That's the command you should give in the command line, not in MySQL itself.

Answer (score -1):

from client you can run `\. mysqldump.sql` but i think first variant is preferable.